# Short LED-strip wiring

Tags: wiring, led-strip

**Look past the fact, that this will electrocute me - just for now.**

I am building a small bowl with LED-strips inside it, and I need to wire it.
The question is - how?

This is my bowl with 24 * 15cm LED-strips (3.60m):

[image: My bowl with led-strips]
It needs to light up, so I "just" have to solder the wires to it.

I would like Option 1 was the best option:

[image: Option 1]

But I might need to do Option 2:

[image: Option 2]

Or Option 3:

[image]

I'm good with computers, but I never really got how to wire stuff.
Can I get some pointers?

Comment: I prefer Option 3.  It minimizes the current in each LED strip.  In option 1, the current for all the strips passes through the top strip.

Comment: @PeterBennett I have that tip, but some glue can fix it, so it starts on the inner circle of the bowl and the wire goes there... Or I drill a hole in the center, and pull the wire from there?

Comment: I agree you should start from the center if possible and wire them all in parallel as shown in 3. I'm not worried about you getting electrocuted with ~5V but some effort should go into making sure that exposed copper on the strips doesn't touch the metal bowl. Otherwise, you'll have a nice looking project that is shorted and doesn't work. Depending on the current capacity of the power supply you may even get complimentary fireworks if you're lucky!

Comment: @MapleTronix A nice bonus with fireworks - everyone love fireworks. I am adding soldering tape under each start and end, but was just reminded the middle parts of each section might suffer from the same. Better get the glue then. And thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the strips came connected as one single long strip, which you cut into smaller pieces.

If that was the case either option will work fine as the first strip in the original configuration would have to handle all the current and work fine.

So it comes down more to preference and practicality - there is a benefit for option 3, the strips at the start won't heat up as much, but heat generation should be dominated by the LEDs and not copper losses.

---

For that (not exactly sure how you want to use it later) I think option 3 and coming in in the middle (drill a hole with a sharp drill, protect the wire from rubbing with the metal) would result in the cleanest looking concept. All the wires would be concentrated in the middle and could be covered with some plastic plate or something like that. Trust me, people will notice the cables dangling around if the thing is not turned on, so hiding them nicely will increase the value immensely.

Be careful that no wire or exposed pad from the strip touches the metal bowl as that can result in short circuits and typical circuits don't work very well then.

Be extra careful to solder each strip correctly - those things look so similar that you can easily get confused with which pad is plus and which is minus.